# How to maximize Chrome in Playwright using c# Nunit

Tags: playwright, playwright-sharp, playwright-dotnet

Below code open Chrome in non maximised state. I can see the code online/youtube used in Java to change the screensize but not found anything for c#.

```
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
            await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
            });
            var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
            // Open new page
            var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
            await page.GotoAsync("https://google.com/");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two things:

1. Pass the [--start-maximized](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) flag to the [Args](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-option-args) of `LaunchOptions`
2. Override the [context-viewport](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context-option-viewport) default configuration with `NoViewport`

```cs
public async Task Test1()
{
    var launchOptions = new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
    {
       Headless = false,
       Args = new List<string> { "--start-maximized" }
    };

    using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        
    await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(launchOptions);

    var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions
    {
        ViewportSize = ViewportSize.NoViewport
    });

    var page = await context.NewPageAsync();

    await page.GotoAsync("https://google.com/");
}
```

Comment: Passing NoViewport literally gave me no Chromium window, i.e. no viewport. I found that my Chromium window was the correct size but was approximately 10 pixels away from the top left corner of the screen. I therefore passed: 

"--start.maximized", "--window-position=-10,0. This did the trick and was almost as good as Maximize. 

I did also try the Height and Width as Nick Graham suggested and it worked but I didn't need to change size in my scenario.

Comment: @Ewan Are you sure you did exactly what I did? (headless false, browser maximized, context noviewport)

Answer (score 1):

I found that `ViewportSize` wouldn't accept `null` but passing in approximate values for a maximised screen got me the same result.

```
BrowserNewContextOptions browserNewContextOptions = new BrowserNewContextOptions();
browserNewContextOptions.ViewportSize = new ViewportSize { Height = 1000, Width = 1900 };
IBrowserContext Context = await browser.NewContextAsync(browserNewContextOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the browser maximized, you need to pass `null` instead of width & height.

I don't have .NET installed, but it should be something like

```
await using
var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions {
    ViewportSize = new ViewportSize() null
});
```